# Not able to run Azure Data Factory Pipeline using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have followed the Azure documentation steps to create a simple Copy Data Factory from Blob to SQL.

Now I want to run the pipeline through VS code.
I have checked the authentication keys and Roles assigned are correct.

Below is the code -

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

Console.WriteLine("Creating pipeline run...");
var st = client.Pipelines.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName);
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName).Result.Body;
Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run ID: " + runResponse.RunId);
```

However, I get `Forbidden error`.

> The client 'xxxx' with object id 'xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

According to the exception message that it indicates that you don't assign the corresponding role to application to access the data factory.

I test your code with Azure Datafactory(V2) on my side , it works correctly. The following is my details steps.

1. [Registry an Azure AD **WebApp** application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).
2. [Get the clientId and clientscret from created Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key).
3. Assign the role the application to access the datafactory.

[image]

4. Test code on my side.

   [image]

Comment: Yes adding the role to Application fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad to know that.